# Why is the mansion called "Rose Red"?

Tags: rose-red

The mini-series [*Rose Red*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0259153/) is about a haunted mansion in Seattle, Washington called Rose Red.

John Rimbauer had the mansion built for his new bride, Ellen.  It was Ellen Rimbauer who gave [Rose Red](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Rose_Red_(house)) it's name:

> In the story, it was supposedly built by John Rimbauer as a wedding
>   gift to his young and beautiful wife Ellen Rimbauer, who gave it its
>   name.

Ellen Rimbauer is seen returning from her honeymoon and stepping out of her carriage.  She looks upon the mansion and calls it Rose Red:

> How beautiful you are, Rose Red.

**Is it ever explained why Ellen Rimbauer called the mansion Rose Red?  What is the meaning behind the name?**

Answer (score 1):

[According to Stephen King](http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/Rose_Red), as stated in a quote on the Stephen King Wikia:

> **Rose Red is a fairy tale for grown-ups.** Not the Disney version of
>   fairy tales, the other kind, where the story doesn't always have a
>   happy ending. The kind in which the old woman in the forest just might
>   put Hansel and Gretel in her pot or the shape under the covers
>   greeting Little Red Riding Hood might gobble her up too. **Think the
>   brothers Grimm, who penned the story of Snow White and her sister,
>   Rose Red, I subconsciously used as a name for my house from hell.** I
>   used all the metaphors, all of the symbols in this story – the evil
>   spirit, the wicked witch, the doppelganger. All of the essential
>   ingredients of Grimm are the basic material. If you think about it,
>   Alice fell through a hole and ended up in Wonderland. Our characters
>   once they find they’re trapped in Rose Red, they’re kind of in a weird
>   and wicked wonderland where things don't make sense or respect the
>   laws of logic. So our big bad wolf is actually a haunted house, a
>   house with a mind of its own. A house that is bigger on the inside
>   than on the outside. A house you could get lost in, and might never
>   find your way back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for an in-universe explanation.  I would have tagged my question with a "title" tag and asked for the author's explanation instead of the character's explanation otherwise.  Thanks :)